# unable to load view from controller in phph - codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new to code igniter framework. I am having issue to call view from controller.

I have 3 three controllers in my application/controllers/ folder
`employee.php`, `home.php` and `dashboard.php`

and 5 views in my views/template/ folder
`header.php`, `footer.php`, `sidebar.php`, `template.php` and `topmenu.php`

and 3 views in my main views folder
`addEmployee.php`, `home.php` and `dashboard.php`

I am able to hit the home and dashboard controller, but unable to hit the employee controller to load addEmployee view.

**this is my addEmployee.php view**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<title>Add Employee</title>
<div class="main-content">
        <?php include 'template/topmenu.php' ?>
        <!-- PAGE CODE STARTS BELOW FROM HERE -->
</div>
```

**employee.php controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Employee extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this -> load -> model('employee_model');

    }

    public function index() {
        $data['header'] = 'template/header';
        $data['sidebar'] = 'template/sidebar';
        $data['main_content'] = 'addEmployee';
        $data['footer'] = 'template/footer';
        $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
    }

    function functionToTestgetAndSaveEmployeeDetailsResult() {

        $result = $this -> getAndSaveEmployeeDetails();
        print_r($result);
    }
}
?>
```

**template/template.php view**

```
<?php defined( 'BASEPATH') OR exit( 'No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php
    $this->load->view($header);
    $this->load->view($sidebar);
    $this->load->view($main_content);
    $this->load->view($footer);
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8050/test/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I am using this url to access the views

```
http://localhost:8050/test/ for home
http://localhost:8050/test/dashbaord for dashbaord
http://localhost:8050/test/addEmployee for addEmployee
```

**home** and **dashboard** views work by this but **addEmployee** doesn't.

I have also tried these url but no luck

```
http://localhost:8050/test/employee/addEmployee 
http://localhost:8050/test/index.php/addEmployee
http://localhost:8050/test/index.php/employee/addEmployee
```

Any idea, what is wrong with this addEmployee view? or any link ?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might be using the wrong URL. To access the page that makes "addEmployee" the "main_content" try

```
http://localhost:8050/test/employee
```

That URL will run `Employee::index()`

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: this comes after using ur url